# Where to find the code for ESRK1 and RSwM1 in the Julia library source code?

Tags: python, math, julia, stochastic, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to implement the SDE solver called ESRK1 and the adaptive stepsize algorithm called RSwM1 from Rackauckas & Nie (2017). I'm writing a python implementation, mainly to confirm to myself that I've understood the algorithm correctly. However, I'm running into a problem already at the implementation of ESRK1: When I test my implementation with shorter and shorter timesteps on a simple SDE describing geometric Brownian motion, the solution does not converge as `dt` becomes smaller, indicating that I have a mistake in my code.

I believe this algorithm is implemented as part of the library DifferentialEquations.jl in Julia, so I thought perhaps I could find some help by looking at the Julia code. However, I have had some trouble locating the relevant code. If someone could point me to the implementation of ESRK1 and RSwM1 in the relevant Julia librar(y/ies) (or indeed any other readable and correct implementation) of these algorithms, I would be most grateful.

I searched for ESRK and RSwM in the github repo of StochasticDiffEq.jl, but I didn't find anything I could really recognise as the method from the paper I'm reading:

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ASciML%2FStochasticDiffEq.jl+rswm&type=code

**Update:**
I found the code for ESRK1, as shown in my answer below, but I'm still unable to find the code for RSwM1.

For completeness, here is my own not-yet-correct implementation of ESRK1 in python:

```
def ESRK1(U, t, dt, f, g, dW, dZ):
    # Implementation of ESRK1, following Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    # Eq. (2), (3) and (4) and Table 1
    
    # Stochastic integrals, taken from Eqs. (25) - (30) in Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    I1   = dW
    I11  = (I1**2 - dt) / 2
    I111 = (I1**3 - 3*dt*I1) / 6
    I10  = (I1 + dZ/np.sqrt(3))*dt / 2
    
    # Coefficients, taken from Table 1 in Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    # All coefficients not included below are zero
    c0_2 = 3/4
    c1_2, c1_3, c1_4 = 1/4, 1, 1/4
    A0_21 = 3/4
    B0_21 = 3/2
    A1_21 = 1/4
    A1_31 = 1
    A1_43 = 1/4
    B1_21 = 1/2
    B1_31 = -1
    B1_41, B1_42, B1_43 = -5, 3, 1/2
    alpha1, alpha2 = 1/2, 2/3
    alpha_tilde1, alpha_tilde2 = 1/2, 1/2
    beta1_1, beta1_2, beta1_3 = -1, 4/3, 2/3
    beta2_1, beta2_2, beta2_3 = -1, 4/3, -1/3
    beta3_1, beta3_2, beta3_3 =  2, -4/3, -2/3
    beta4_1, beta4_2, beta4_3, beta4_4 = -2, 5/3, -2/3, 1
    
    # Stages in the Runge-Kutta approximation
    # Eqs. (3) and (4) and Table 1 in Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    # First stages
    H0_1 = U # H^(0)_1
    H1_1 = U
    # Second stages
    H0_2 = U + A0_21 * f(t, H0_1)*dt + B0_21 * g(t, H1_1)*I10/dt
    H1_2 = U + A1_21 * f(t, H0_1)*dt + B1_21 * g(t, H1_1)*np.sqrt(dt)
    # Third stages
    H0_3 = U
    H1_3 = U + A1_31 * f(t, H0_1) * dt + B1_31 * g(t, H1_1) * np.sqrt(dt)
    # Fourth stages
    H0_4 = U
    H1_4 = U + A1_43 * f(t, H0_3) * dt + (B1_41 * g(t, H1_1) + B1_42 * g(t+c1_2*dt, H1_2) + B1_43 * g(t+c1_3*dt, H1_3)) * np.sqrt(dt)
    
    # Construct next position
    # Eq. (2) and Table 1 in Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    U_ = U  + (alpha1*f(t, H0_1) + alpha2*f(t+c0_2*dt, H0_2))*dt \
            + (beta1_1*I1 + beta2_1*I11/np.sqrt(dt) + beta3_1*I10/dt ) * g(t, H1_1) \
            + (beta1_2*I1 + beta2_2*I11/np.sqrt(dt) + beta3_2*I10/dt ) * g(t + c1_2*dt, H1_2) \
            + (beta1_3*I1 + beta2_3*I11/np.sqrt(dt) + beta3_3*I10/dt ) * g(t + c1_3*dt, H1_3) \
            + (beta4_4*I111/dt ) * g(t + c1_4*dt, H1_4)
    
    # Calculate error estimate
    # Eq. (9) and Table 1 in Rackauckas & Nie (2017)
    E = -dt*(f(t, H0_1) + f(t + c0_2*dt, H0_2))/6  \
        + (beta3_1*I10/dt + beta4_1*I111/dt)*g(t, H1_1) \
        + (beta3_2*I10/dt + beta4_2*I111/dt)*g(t + c1_2*dt, H1_2) \
        + (beta3_3*I10/dt + beta4_3*I111/dt)*g(t + c1_3*dt, H1_3) \
        + (beta4_4*I111/dt)*g(t + c1_4*dt, H1_4)

    # Return next position and error
    return U_, E
```

Rackauckas & Nie (2017): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5844583/pdf/nihms920388.pdf

Comment: is it this? https://github.com/SciML/OrdinaryDiffEq.jl/blob/master/src/algorithms/explicit_rk.jl

Comment: No, that looks like code for ODE methods, while I'm looking for an SDE method. I would have thought I might find something in StochasticDiffEq.jl, but searching didn't show me anything I recognised: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ASciML%2FStochasticDiffEq.jl+rswm&type=code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess I found the first half of the answer to my question: The code for the ESRK1 method appears to be found in two places in StochasticDiffEq.jl:

The coefficients from the paper (although they are now called SRIW1 instead of ESRK1) here:

https://github.com/SciML/StochasticDiffEq.jl/blob/9d8eb5503f1d78cdb0de76691af2a89c20085486/src/tableaus.jl#L40

and the method (which can also work with other coefficients) here:

https://github.com/SciML/StochasticDiffEq.jl/blob/9d8eb5503f1d78cdb0de76691af2a89c20085486/src/perform_step/sri.jl#L58

It's not super readable, at least not to a non-Julia programmer like me, as it's making use of some advanced features, but I think I'll be able to work it out with a bit of patience.

**Update:**

By translating the Julia code into Python I was able to write an implementation that at least seems to work in the sense that I observe an order 1.5 convergence in the strong sense when I'm testing it as if it was a fixed-step integrator. In case it may be of use to anyone else, here is the line-for-line translation.

```
#   c₀ = [0; 3//4; 0; 0]
c0 = np.array([0, 3/4, 0, 0])

#   c₁ = [0; 1//4; 1; 1//4]
c1 = np.array([0, 1/4, 1, 1/4])

#  A₀ = [0 0 0 0
#      3//4 0 0 0
#      0 0 0 0
#      0 0 0 0]
A0 = np.array([
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
    [3/4, 0, 0, 0],
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
])

#  A₁ = [0 0 0 0
#      1//4 0 0 0
#      1 0 0 0
#      0 0 1//4 0]
A1 = np.array([
    [0,   0,   0, 0],
    [1/4, 0,   0, 0],
    [1,   0,   0, 0],
    [0,   0, 1/4, 0],
])

#  B₀ = [0 0 0 0
#      3//2 0 0 0
#      0 0 0 0
#      0 0 0 0]
B0 = np.array([
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
    [3/2, 0, 0, 0],
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
    [0,   0, 0, 0],
])

#  B₁ = [0 0 0 0
#      1//2 0 0 0
#      -1 0 0 0
#      -5 3 1//2 0]
B1 = np.array([
    [0,   0,   0, 0],
    [1/2, 0,   0, 0],
    [-1,  0,   0, 0],
    [-5,  3, 1/2, 0],
])

#  α = [1//3; 2//3; 0;0]
alpha = np.array([ 1/3,  2/3,    0, 0])

#  β₁ = [-1; 4//3; 2//3; 0]
beta1 = np.array([-1,   4/3,  2/3, 0])

#  β₂ = -[1; -4//3; 1//3; 0]
beta2 = np.array([-1,    4/3,  -1/3, 0])

#  β₃ = [2; -4//3; -2//3; 0]
beta3 = np.array([ 2,   -4/3, -2/3, 0])

#  β₄ = [-2; 5//3; -2//3; 1]
beta4 = np.array([-2,    5/3, -2/3, 1])

def ESRK1(U, t, dt, f, g, dW=None, dZ=None):
    # sqrt3 = sqrt(3one(eltype(W.dW)))
    sqrt3 = np.sqrt(3)
    # chi1 = (W.dW.^2 - abs(dt))/2integrator.sqdt #I_(1,1)/sqrt(h)
    chi1 = (dW**2 - np.abs(dt)) / (2*np.sqrt(dt))
    # chi2 = (W.dW + W.dZ/sqrt3)/2 #I_(1,0)/h
    chi2 = (dW + dZ/sqrt3)/2
    # chi3 = (W.dW.^3 - 3W.dW*dt)/6dt #I_(1,1,1)/h
    chi3 = (dW**3 - 3*dW*dt) / (6*dt)

    
    # for i=1:stages
    #   fill!(H0[i],zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    #   fill!(H1[i],zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    # end
    stages = 4
    H0 = np.zeros(stages)
    H1 = np.zeros(stages)
    
    # for i = 1:stages
    #    fill!(A0temp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    #    fill!(B0temp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    #    fill!(A1temp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    #    fill!(B1temp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    for i in range(stages):
        A0temp = 0.0
        B0temp = 0.0
        A1temp = 0.0
        B1temp = 0.0
        
       # for j = 1:i-1
       #   integrator.f(ftemp,H0[j],p,t + c₀[j]*dt)
       #   integrator.g(gtemp,H1[j],p,t + c₁[j]*dt)
       #   @.. A0temp = A0temp + A₀[j,i]*ftemp
       #   @.. B0temp = B0temp + B₀[j,i]*gtemp
       #   @.. A1temp = A1temp + A₁[j,i]*ftemp
       #   @.. B1temp = B1temp + B₁[j,i]*gtemp
       # end
        
        for j in range(i):
            ftemp = f(H0[j], t+c0[j]*dt)
            gtemp = g(H1[j], t+c1[j]*dt)
            A0temp = A0temp + A0[i,j]*ftemp
            B0temp = B0temp + B0[i,j]*gtemp
            A1temp = A1temp + A1[i,j]*ftemp
            B1temp = B1temp + B1[i,j]*gtemp
            
       # @.. H0[i] = uprev + A0temp*dt + B0temp*chi2
       # @.. H1[i] = uprev + A1temp*dt + B1temp*integrator.sqdt
       # end
        H0[i] = U[0] + A0temp*dt + B0temp*chi2
        H1[i] = U[0] + A1temp*dt + B1temp*np.sqrt(dt)
        
    
     # fill!(atemp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
     # fill!(btemp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
     # fill!(E₂,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
     # fill!(E₁temp,zero(eltype(integrator.u)))
    
    atemp = 0.0
    btemp = 0.0
    E2 = 0.0
    E1temp = 0.0
    
    
     # for i = 1:stages
     #   integrator.f(ftemp,H0[i],p,t+c₀[i]*dt)
     #   integrator.g(gtemp,H1[i],p,t+c₁[i]*dt)
     #   @.. atemp = atemp + α[i]*ftemp
     #   @.. btemp = btemp + (β₁[i]*W.dW + β₂[i]*chi1)*gtemp
     #   @.. E₂    = E₂    + (β₃[i]*chi2 + β₄[i]*chi3)*gtemp
     #   if i <= error_terms
     #     @.. E₁temp += ftemp
     # end
        
    for i in range(stages):
        ftemp = f(H0[i], t+c0[i]*dt)
        gtemp = g(H1[i], t+c1[i]*dt)
        atemp = atemp + alpha[i]*ftemp
        btemp = btemp + (beta1[i]*dW   + beta2[i]*chi1)*gtemp
        E2    = E2    + (beta3[i]*chi2 + beta4[i]*chi3)*gtemp
            
    # @.. u = uprev + (dt*atemp + btemp) + E₂
    return U + (dt*atemp + btemp) + E2
```